# Reading a windows file without preventing another process from writing to it

Tags: python, windows, delphi, winapi, filesystems

I have a file that I want to read. The file may at any time be overwritten by another process. I do not want to block that writing. I am prepared to manage corruption to the data that I read, but do not want my reading to be in any way change the behaviour of the writing process.

The process that is writing the file is a delphi program running locally on the server. It opens the file using fmCreate. fmCreate tries to open the file exclusively and fails if there are any other handles on the file.

I am reading the file from a python script that accesses the file remotely across our network.

I am interested in whether there is a solution, independent of whether it is supported by python or delphi. I want to know if there is any way of achieving this under windows without modifying the writing program.

Edit: To reiterate, this is not a duplicate. The other question was trying to get read access to a file that is being written to. I want to the writer to have access to a file that I have open for reading. These are different questions (although I fear the answer will be similar, that it can't be done.)

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference whether your process or the other process opens the file first.  Your options are pretty much the same either way.

Comment: Are you trying to see the new data in real-time as it is written to the file?

Comment: @RichardA I think you can delete the question and post a new one, rephrasing the text to ensure that it's not treated as a duplicate. Yet if you check my answer, you don't need another question.

Comment: I still don't think it makes any difference which process opens the file first, so your additional note isn't really relevant.  On the other hand, you're accessing the file remotely, and you haven't ruled out kernel mode drivers, so perhaps not an exact duplicate.

Comment: The short answer is if the client doesn't have admin access to the server there's no way to do this remotely, you would have to install additional software on the server to read the file on behalf of the client process.  This could use either VSS as per the other question or a filter driver as per Eugene's answer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Set of solutions is different depending who the first and who's the second to open the file.

Comment: @Eugene: can you justify that?  Give an example of a solution that only works in one of those cases?  (I've already voted to reopen.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's obvious - if exclusive read is the second operation (3rdparty app), using tricks to bypass security won't work for the first open operation (our app). If 3rdparty app opened the file first, we would be able to use eg. our RawDisk to open the file which has been already opened exclusively.

Comment: I don't see why not.  If you can read the file without opening it, why would the other app be affected?  Specific tools might only support one scenario, but any given technique should be applicable to either, with minor variations.

Comment: Thanks for all the discussion. @HarryJohnston, I thought the order of opening might make a difference, as the reading process is opening it non-exclusively first, then the writing process is trying to open exclusively. The reading process does not want to read the new data in real-time, it is prepared to abort reading and try to access the file once the new data is written.

Comment: At the risk of labouring the point, I believe the other question was regarding trying to read a file that is being written to. I want to be able to write to a file that is being read, even though the writing terminates the reading. To me these a different problems.

Comment: According to your question, you want to read the file.  It's somebody else (i.e., somebody else's code) that's writing to it.  In Windows, I don't think the order in which this happens should make much difference to the possible range of solutions, or at least not in principle.  OTOH, @Eugene is clearly more experienced in the practical aspects of this sort of trickery, so there's a good chance he's seeing some subtlety that I've missed.

Comment: To clarify, in Windows, when you acquire a sharing lock on a file the lock is treated perfectly symmetrically; that is, the question of whether or not your lock is compatible with another existing or future lock on the same file does not depend upon which lock came first.  It would be entirely possible to design an operating system in which this was not true, but it is true in Windows.  (So the only options are to either read the file using some method which does not acquire a lock at all, or to modify the other process either directly or indirectly.)

Comment: I'm certainly no expert in this. The reason I thought there was a lack of symmetry is that the reader is opening the file with OF_SHARE_DENY_NONE, whereas the writer is opening it with OF_CREATE; so the locks are not equal.

Comment: Yes, but that's presumably true regardless of whether the reader or the writer opens the file first.  They're still going to use the same sharing flags either way.

Comment: I'm sure you're right. I only have a simplistic understanding of the underlying operating system functionality. I was just hoping, perhaps naively, that there was some way of allowing one process to grab the file if the other process had opened it with the right flag. I think me hopes are dashed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the real answer here, all of these years later, is to use **opportunistic locks**. With this, you can open the file for read access, while telling the OS that you want to be notified if another program wants to access the file. Basically, you can use the file as long as you like, and then back off if someone else needs it. This avoids the sharing/access violation that the other program would normally get, if you had just opened the file "normally".

There is [an MSDN article on Opportunistic Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/opportunistic-locks). Raymond Chen also has a blog article about this, complete with sample code: [Using opportunistic locks to get out of the way if somebody wants the file](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130415-00/?p=4663)

The key is calling the `DeviceIoControl` function, with the `FSCTL_REQUEST_OPLOCK` flag, and passing it the handle to an event that you previously created by calling `CreateEvent`.

It should be straightforward to use this from Delphi, since it supports calling Windows API functions. I am not so sure about Python. But, given the arrangement in the question, it should not be necessary to modify the Python code. Just make your Delphi code use the opportunistic lock when it opens the file, and let it get out of the way when the Python script needs the file.

Also much easier and lighter weight than a filter driver or the Volume Shadow Copy service.

Comment: what's your problem, biological technician?

Comment: @DickWilliams Sorry, what are you talking about?

Comment: @DickWilliams I provided you with a reason why I deleted the answer. It wasn't personal. I have nothing against you or your other contributions, which add something novel to the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a filter driver which can act in two ways: (1) modify the flags when the file is opened, and (2) it can capture the data when it's written to the file and save a copy of the data elsewhere.

This approach is much more lightweight and efficient than volume shadow copy service, mentioned in comments, however it requires having a filter driver. There exist several drivers on the market (i.e. those are products which include a driver and let you write business logic in user mode) yet they are costly and can be an overkill in your case. Still, if you need the thing for private use only, contact me privately for a license for our CallbackFilter.

Update: if you want to let the writer open the file which has been already opened, then a filter which will modify flags when the file is being opened is your only option.

Comment: Regarding your final comment: surely a filter could extract the data from a file without opening it, eliminating the need for the reader to open the file at all?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Eugene. I don't know much about filter drivers, so appreciate the lead.